# Translating objects in nodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have the following object that I need to transform into a slightly different format. I'm pretty sure I can use nodes native `map` function to translate it. e.g.

```js
var animals = [ 
  [ 'cats', 1726, 1143, 10, 105, 2382, 0 ],
  [ 'dogs', 640, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
  [ 'cows' 13509, 0, 3, 1, 196939, 19 ],
  [ 'sheep', 1573, 1084, 10, 105, 2266, 0 ]
             ]
```

Into this format:

```js
new_animals = [{
    name: 'cats',
    data: [1726, 1143, 10, 105, 2382, 0]
  }, {
    name: 'dogs',
    data: [640, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
  }, {
    name: 'cows',
    data: [13509, 0, 3, 1, 196939, 19]
  },
  {
    name: 'sheep',
    data: [1573, 1084, 10, 105, 2266, 0]
  }]
```

Comment: You most definitely can. Have you tried it? And for what it's worth, `map` is built-in to JavaScript, it isn't a Node.js thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using ES2015 features:

```
const newAnimals = animals.map(([name, ...data]) => ({ name, data }));
```

Without ES2015 features:

```
var newAnimals = animals.map(function (animal) {
  return {
    name: animal[0],
    data: animal.slice(1)
  };
});
```

Comment: This is why I added the second version. The first one is very succinct, but also quite hard to understand, because it uses a lot of new features.

Answer (score 0):

its actually quite simple:

```js
var animals = [
    ['cats', 1726, 1143, 10, 105, 2382, 0],
    ['dogs', 640, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    ['cows', 13509, 0, 3, 1, 196939, 19],
    ['sheep', 1573, 1084, 10, 105, 2266, 0]
];

console.log(animals.map(([name, ...data]) => ({name, data})));
```

alternative if your node version does not support lambdas:

```
animals.map(function (animal) {
    return {
        name: animal.shift(),
        data: animal
    };
});
```